# Assigning Multidimensional Array in VHDL

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, vhdl, variable-assignment, circular-buffer

I am trying to assign a multidimensional array in VHDL. I've tried the code below but the compiler throws an error saying "the assignment type is different from expression type". The datatype of `data_in` is std_logic, so I'm trying to save a single bit inside the ring buffer.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do that?

Regards,
Tobi

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity Sensor is 
    port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    data_in : in std_logic
);

end Sensor;

architecture BEHAVIOR of Sensor is

type ram_t is array (0 to 255) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal ram : ram_t := (others => (others => '0'));
signal ram_write_pointer : natural := 0;

begin

CONTROL_PROCESS : process(clk)
begin

  if rising_edge(clk) then
     -- fill ring buffer            
     ram(ram_write_pointer / 8 )(ram_write_pointer mod 8) <= data_in;
     ram_write_pointer <= ram_write_pointer + 1;
     if ram_write_pointer > 2040 then
        ram_write_pointer <= 0;
     end if;
  end if;
 end process;

end BEHAVIOR;
```

Comment: Make an MCVE of this. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (And is there any reason for only using 1/8 of the buffer?)

Comment: Almost there for the MCVE, now show the entire error message. This code analyzes, although the mod operator is not what you want.

Comment: `type ram_t is array (0 to 255) of ...` isn't a multidimensional array, it's a single dimensional array with an element type that's an array type. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2 Array types. A multidimensional array type would have an index constraint with comma separated discrete ranges. You're likely trying to access both by element and element of an element. A byte wide RAM may be lacking in write steering for bits, implying either an assembling buffer (a shift register) or read-modify-write. The shift register is easier. Should be `if ram_write_pointer = 2047 then ram_write_pointer <= 0;`.

Comment: Synthesizes well with ISE 14.7 and Quartus-II 13.1. So which tool are you using? Of course, actually no hardware is generated as the design has no output.

Answer (score 0):

ghdl 0.33 compiles this just fine. Which compiler are you using?

Meanwhile I'm going to take a wild guess that you are compiling with a synthesis tool, (which is allowed to pick and choose what VHDL it supports) and that it doesn't support bit-level addressing in byte-wide memories.

If that's the case, then mapping the buffer to a 2048 * 1-bit wide RAM should work perfectly. And as a bonus, your write pointer code will become simpler and less bug-prone (at the moment I believe it does the wrong thing when `ram_write_pointer` hits 2040)